# Creating a Brush made of a left, middle, right image where the middle image gets tiled

Tags: c#, wpf, visualbrush

I need to create a brush in WPF that will be used as a background for a panel. The brush has a fixed height but variable width. The middle image needs to tile to fill up the space while the left and right images are fixed. I tried with a VisualBrush and a grid with images but it just doesn't align/scale correctly. Here's a drawing brush that works for fixed width. How do I make it work so that it tiles the middle image for panels of variable width?

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="Background">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
                <ImageDrawing Rect="0 0 16 16" ImageSource="Resources/Left.png"/>
                <ImageDrawing Rect="16 0 16 16" ImageSource="Resources/Middle.png"/>
                <ImageDrawing Rect="48 0 16 16" ImageSource="Resources/Right.png"/>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

Comment: Have you looked at [TileBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.tilemode.aspx)?

Comment: The DrawingBrush is a TileBrush. The TileMode applies to the entire brush not just part of it. That's why I am asking if it's possible to combine multiple brushes (with different tile modes) into a single brush.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can actually do that, so as an alternative use a Binding and Converter to generate a new Brush to fit the appropriate size.

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="16,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Background="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Converter={StaticResource widthToBrushConverter}}"/>
```

and in Width to brush converter

```
public class WidthToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var width = (double)value;

        var result = new DrawingBrush();
        var group = new DrawingGroup();
        result.Drawing = group;

        group.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Resources\Left.png", UriKind.Relative)), new Rect(0, 0, 16, 16)));
        group.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Resources\Centre.png", UriKind.Relative)), new Rect(16, 0, width, 16)));
        group.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Resources\Right.png", UriKind.Relative)), new Rect(16 + width, 0, 16, 16)));
        return result;
    }
```

**UPDATE**
The only problem is this doesn't seem to work. I just get a black screen